# horizontal pager in windows phone

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone-8, scrollview

I am writing application in windows phone 8.

I am trying to implement horizontal pager in windows phone like bellow link

[Horizontal pager for android](https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager)

how can i implement horizontal animation in windows phone?

Comment: Can't you just use a horizontal ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck because it's already implemented!! In Windows Phone this is called the [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Visual Studio even makes it easy to create an app with a Pivot with the "Windows Phone Pivot App" project. Or you can simply add a Pivot Page to a project that you already have. If you have dynamic content you can set the ItemsSource of the Pivot to be a collection of objects and then set the ItemTemplate to look like however you want it to look.

```
<phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo}"/?
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Also here is a handy [article for adding "pips"](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2011/12/08/a-windows-phone-7-slide-view-with-page-pips.html) to the Pivot.

Comment: :thanks but this will not fulfill my requirement.Actully  I have one chart control and when I am swipe my page at that time I want set slide animation in same control so how can I set?

Comment: You might be looking for the Panorama control then. In Visual Studio create a new "Windows Phone Panorama App". Look at the second PanoramaItem. It scrolls horizontally. You can replace the Borders with a chart control!